# image folder doesn't create in war file

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have a folder named 'uploads' in my spring boot project directory where i upload my dynamic images required (not static images)
but whenever i create war file it doesn't create that folder. folder disappears.
what should i do?
or where should i upload my images(dynamic).
my project structure is as follows
i use `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/uploads";` this code to get my parent directory

thanks un advance
[project structure here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw0Lv.png)

Answer (score 0):

This method can help you to create folder anywhere you want

```
private static File fileWithDirectory(String directory, String filename) {
    File dir = new File(directory);
    if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
    return new File(directory + "/" + filename);
}
```

Comment: 'uploads' folder doesn't get created when i create war file of project.

Comment: Folder will be created when this code will be executed at least once.

Comment: when i upload and extract my war file on my website "System.getProperty("user.dir")" becomes null.

Comment: "user.dir" dose this exist in your properties file?

Comment: Full path of your directory like C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Packages\